# Adding data to a database but it does not reflect on the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, .net-core

I am new to C# and ADO.net. I am using a local DB and have a method that adds data to a database but the data does not reflect once this method has been called. Although, when I do add data I can access it from my retrieve data method. Although when the program is shut down that data is lost. Can you please help me.Could it have something to do with my connection String. Here is my insert method:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Customers (Username, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, CreditStatus, HomeAddress, Password, Blacklisted, Email) " +
               "VALUES (@Username, @FirstName, @LastName, @PhoneNumber, @CreditStatus, @HomeAddress, @Password,@Blacklisted,@Email) ";

private string strConn = Settings.Default.OrderingDBConnectionString;

// The val of strConn:
// Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseLayer\OrderingDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True

public void insert(Customer customer) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(strConn);

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            
    cn.Open();
    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", customer.getUsername());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", customer.getFirstName());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", customer.getLastName());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", customer.getPhoneNumber());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreditStatus", customer.getCreditStatus());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", customer.getAddress());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", customer.getPassword());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Blacklisted", customer.getBlacklisted());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", customer.getEmail());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: If you use `int rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` - what value do you get? Are any rows even inserted at all?

Answer (score 1):

use try catch to see if the connection is opened correctly or not and see other error:

```
        {
            try  
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", customer.getUsername());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", customer.getFirstName());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", customer.getLastName());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", customer.getPhoneNumber());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreditStatus", customer.getCreditStatus());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", customer.getAddress());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", customer.getPassword());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Blacklisted", customer.getBlacklisted());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", customer.getEmail());

                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
            } 
        }
```

Probably the problem is the connectionString